# Why I can't save my connector on Microsoft Teams?

Tags: microsoft-teams, connector

I made a custom connector for teams that display notifications on channels and add Tab on teams.

For the tab parts -> Everything is working well

But I have a problem for the connector parts, I get an error when I try to save my settings in the developer console:

```
Received error from connectors {"seq":1585127802210,"timestamp":1585127814174,"flightSettings":{"Name":"ConnectorFrontEndSettings","AriaSDKT....
```

-> registerOnSaveHandler is called
-> setSettings is correctly set with entityId, contentUrl (same configurationUrl as the connector configuration) and the configName. 
getSettings -> is called to save to my app the webhook url -> it works
-> notifySuccess is then called and

I checked on the connector dashboard everything seems fine, on the App Studio everything is green also!

I don't know what is happening..

My manifest

```
{
"$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/json-schemas/teams/v1.5/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
"manifestVersion": "1.5",
"version": "1.0.0",
"id": "ca153ede-92f2-46e7-8695-3726b5343bf4",
"packageName": "com.kagilum.icescrum",
"developer": {
    "name": "Kagilum SAS",
    "websiteUrl": "https://www.icescrum.com",
    "privacyUrl": "https://www.icescrum.com/privacy",
    "termsOfUseUrl": "https://www.icescrum.com/termsofuser"
},
"icons": {
    "color": "color.png",
    "outline": "outline.png"
},
"name": {
    "short": "iceScrum",
    "full": "Connect with iceScrum"
},
"description": {
    "short": "A true Agile project management tool",
    "full": "iceScrum is a web application for using Scrum while keeping the spirit of a collaborative workspace. It also offers virtual boards with post-its for sprint backlog, product backlog and others."
},
"accentColor": "#FFFFFF",
"configurableTabs": [
    {
        "configurationUrl": "https://preview.icescrum.com/msTeams/setupTab/",
        "canUpdateConfiguration": true,
        "scopes": [
            "team",
            "groupchat"
        ],
        "supportedSharePointHosts": [
            "sharePointFullPage",
            "sharePointWebPart"
        ]
    }
],
"connectors": [
    {
        "connectorId": "f00d8890-daa8-4c87-89f5-83cbab0bccd4",
        "configurationUrl": "https://preview.icescrum.com/msTeams/setup/",
        "scopes": [
            "team"
        ]
    }
],
"permissions": [
    "identity",
    "messageTeamMembers"
],
"validDomains": [
    "preview.icescrum.com"
]
```

}

Piece of code related to

```
microsoftTeams.settings.registerOnSaveHandler(function(saveEvent) {
        microsoftTeams.settings.setSettings({
            entityId: 'icescrum-pkey-' + $scope.settings.project.pkey,
            contentUrl: isSettings.serverUrl + '/msTeams/setup/',
            configName: $scope.settings.project.name
        });
        microsoftTeams.settings.getSettings(function(settings) {
            $scope.settings.webhookUrl = settings.webhookUrl;
            return FormService.httpPost('msTeams/save', $scope.settings, true).then(function() {
                saveEvent.notifySuccess(); //wait that the settings are really saved on iceScrum side
            });
        });
    });
    microsoftTeams.settings.getSettings(function(settings) {
        $scope.setup = !settings.configName;
        var tokenData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("msTeams-oauth"));
        var userData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("msTeams-user"));
        if (tokenData) {
            FormService.httpGet('ws/project/user/' + userData.id + '?light=true', {headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + tokenData['accessToken']}}, true).then(function(projects) {
                $scope.projects = projects;
                if (settings.entityId) {
                    $scope.settings.project = _.find($scope.projects, {pkey: settings.entityId.split('icescrum-pkey-')[1]});
                }
                $scope.ready = true;
            });
        }
    });
```

Full error:

```
angular.min.js:113 2020-03-25T20:35:25.953Z Received error from connectors {"seq":1585168484680,"timestamp":1585168525943,"flightSettings":{"Name":"ConnectorFrontEndSettings","AriaSDKToken":"d127f72a3abd41c9b9dd94faca947689-d58285e6-3a68-4cab-a458-37b9d9761d35-7033","SPAEnabled":true,"ClassificationFilterEnabled":true,"ClientRoutingEnabled":true,"EnableYammerGroupOption":true,"EnableFadeMessage":false,"EnableDomainBasedOwaConnectorList":false,"EnableDomainBasedTeamsConnectorList":false,"DevPortalSPAEnabled":true,"ShowHomeNavigationButtonOnConfigurationPage":false,"DisableConnectToO365InlineDeleteFeedbackPage":true},"status":500,"clientType":"SkypeSpaces","connectorType":"f00d8890-daa8-4c87-89f5-83cbab0bccd4","name":"handleMessageError"}
```

Comment: i am facing the same error. any updates ? did u figure out what was the problem ?

Comment: Same issue here. No end in sight.

Comment: Answered below what solves this for me.

Answer (score 1):

In case this helps anyone else, I spent ages today trying to get to the bottom of this and couldn't find a solution.  Until...as a last gasp show of desperation I decide to use App Studio to recreate the entire connector manifest from scratch, including creating a new connector in the portal.

For some reason, this then worked fine - even though I can see that the two manifest files are *identical* with the exception of the ID (and I already tried regenerating the ID for the original one).

Answer (score 0):

Bit late to the story, but having followed multiple github issues [like this](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/msteams-docs/issues/2247) and stack overflow posts, I'm pretty convinced that its the problem with Connectors dashboard. If you made any change to settings, they are not really propageted/saved correctly.

So for example, if you changed validDomains or configurationPage URL, they won't actually do anything. You can verify that with your devtools. For me, after changing the configurationPage the Teams is still making request to old URL as well as the new one, but the old request produces error that's listed in question.

The only workaround I was able to find is to recreate connector in dashboard. Reported problem to MS Teams dev team, waiting to hear back.

Comment: Tried this and it still did not work :(

Comment: Hello @BrandonMedenwald - Could you please share the teamsJs version on which you have tried this scenario. Also, please share the Teams client details, so that we can try to repro it from our end?

Comment: Meanwhile, could you please check this sample, if it can help you in any way: https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/connector-generic/nodejs

Comment: Using 1.12.1 now, but reproduce bug in 1.11.0 and 1.6.0. Using teams.microsoft.com so no version number is necessary (though reproducible in latest Mac desktop app as well.

Comment: @ChetanSharma-msft See my issue with code examples here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75229408/notifysuccess-on-saveevent-not-working-seeing-error-in-console

Comment: @BrandonMedenwald - We have tested this with Teams JS version 2.7.1. We created custom connector. registerOnSaveHandler is called but saveEvent.notifySuccess is not called and Save button is not enabled. We have raised a bug for the same. We will keep you posted if there are any updates on it. Thanks

Comment: @BrandonMedenwald - We tested this on Teams Desktop Client 1.6.00.2359 on Windows 11. and Teams JS version 2.7.1.

Comment: Answered this based on what eventually worked for me. Either bugs or very poor documentation, or both.

Answer (score 0):

Also late here, but I ran into this problem and the below was the solution after 3 days of frustration.

Despite everything mentioned in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/create-tab-pages/configuration-page?tabs=teamsjs-v1), the following is required otherwise you'll get this error. This fixed things for me.

```js
microsoftTeams.settings.registerOnSaveHandler(saveEvent => {
  microsoftTeams.settings.setSettings({
    contentUrl: "https://xxxxxx.ngrok.io/teams/connector"
  });

  saveEvent.notifySuccess();
});
```

The documentation states that registering a save handler is optional and Teams will handle notify success if it's not declared. **WRONG**. You must register a save handler.

The documentation does not state that `setSettings` is required. **WRONG**. You must set settings or else you will receive this error.

The documentation does not state that you must save a `contentURL`. **WRONG**. You must set content URL in the `setSettings`. You can apparently omit other things when setting your settings, but not content URL.

The documentation does not specifically mention it, but the `contentURL` must comply with your `validURLs` in your manifest. If it does not, you'll also see this error.

So in your case, you must ensure that `isSettings.serverUrl` (`setSettings()` `contentURL`) does match `preview.icescrum.com` (manifest `validURLs`). If they do not, you'll see this error.