# notifySuccess on saveEvent not working, seeing error in console

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-teams-js

I'm trying to build a screen to save a connector and I cannot get the Save button to work. It throws a JavaScript error from deep inside Teams itself.

As you can see I'm using the latest stable version of Teams JS.

My code has been boiled down to as simple as can be made. It just inits and sets the Save button validity so it can be clicked.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src="https://res.cdn.office.net/teams-js/2.7.1/js/MicrosoftTeams.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Testing 6</p>

    <script>
      async function init() {
        await microsoftTeams.app.initialize();
        microsoftTeams.pages.config.setValidityState(true);
      }

      init();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

If I load up the console in my web browser, this is the error I receive:

```json
2023-01-25T03:00:00.927Z Received error from connectors {
  "seq":1674609016862,
  "timestamp":1674613638241,
  "flightSettings":{
    "Name":"ConnectorFrontEndSettings",
    "AriaSDKToken":"d12...",
    "SPAEnabled":true,
    "ClassificationFilterEnabled":true,
    "ClientRoutingEnabled":true,
    "EnableYammerGroupOption":true,
    "EnableFadeMessage":false,
    "EnableDomainBasedOwaConnectorList":false,
    "EnableDomainBasedTeamsConnectorList":false,
    "DevPortalSPAEnabled":true,
    "ShowHomeNavigationButtonOnConfigurationPage":false,
    "DisableConnectToO365InlineDeleteFeedbackPage":true,
    "RemoveAnchorHeader":true
  },
  "status":500,
  "clientType":"SkypeSpaces",
  "connectorType":"92a...",
  "name":"handleMessageError"
}
```

The manifest file is also simple: it is the one downloaded from the Connector Dashboard (with the invalid part deleted and the schema version upgraded because the dashboard generates INVALID MANIFESTS). Because I've downloaded the file, the UUIDs and valid domains are perfect matches.

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/json-schemas/teams/v1.15/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
  "manifestVersion": "1.15",
  "id": "2ac21268...",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "packageName": "com.Simple I/O (Development 3)",
  "developer": {
    "name": "Developer",
    "websiteUrl": "https://3821-68-69-235-13.ngrok.io",
    "privacyUrl": "https://3821-68-69-235-13.ngrok.io",
    "termsOfUseUrl": "https://3821-68-69-235-13.ngrok.io"
  },
  "description": {
    "full": "Simple I/O (Development 3)",
    "short": "Simple I/O (Development 3)"
  },
  "icons": {
    "outline": "outline.png",
    "color": "color.png"
  },
  "connectors": [
    {
      "connectorId": "2ac21268...",
      "scopes": [
        "team"
      ],
      "configurationUrl": "https://3821-68-69-235-13.ngrok.io/teams/connector"
    }
  ],
  "name": {
    "full": "Simple I/O (Development 3)",
    "short": "Simple I/O (Development 3)"
  },
  "accentColor": "#FFFFFF",
  "validDomains": [
    "3821-68-69-235-13.ngrok.io"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Update on this: still very broken. If I change the code above to call `notifyFailure()` instead of success, it insta-fails (as it should). So the problem has to be somewhere inside the `notifySuccess()`, which explains why it also fails if I don't register a save handler (the docs suggest is calls `notifySuccess()` automatically.

Comment: Hello @Brandon - Did you get a chance to try it with latest TeamsJS version? Also, are you facing this issue in Teams Desktop client?if yes, could you please share your Teams client version details?

Comment: @ChetanSharma-msft I'm using teams.microsoft.com so the version number is irrelevant (though I'm able to reproduce all these problems in the Mac app version 1.5.00.33356). Regarding the Teams JS version, I moved all the way to 1.12.1 with no fix. I shouldn't have to rewrite all my code everywhere else to v2 and promises just to get this configuration page to work, right?

Comment: @ChetanSharma-msft Updated above with more code samples. As you can see, I've now built a brand new, boiled down, self contained example with almost no code and it still doesn't work. Using the website (so I have the latest Teams) and I'm using the latest stable version of Teams JS. Everything still broken.

Comment: @BrandonMedenwald - We have tested this with Teams JS version 2.7.1. We created custom connector. registerOnSaveHandler is called but saveEvent.notifySuccess is not called and Save button is not enabled.

We have raised a bug for the same. We will keep you posted if there are any updates on it.

Comment: @BrandonMedenwald - We tested this on Teams Desktop Client 1.6.00.2359 on Windows 11. and Teams JS version 2.7.1

Comment: @ChetanSharma-msft I've solved my issue below, the documentation is VERY WRONG and does not state what is required. The error messages generated are deep inside your Angular JS code and do not properly notify the use of what is required either, so developers like me are left stumbling in the dark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite everything mentioned in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/create-tab-pages/configuration-page?tabs=teamsjs-v1), the following is required otherwise you'll get this error. This fixed things for me.

```js
microsoftTeams.settings.registerOnSaveHandler(saveEvent => {
  microsoftTeams.settings.setSettings({
    contentUrl: "https://xxxxxx.ngrok.io/teams/connector"
  });

  saveEvent.notifySuccess();
});
```

The documentation states that registering a save handler is optional and Teams will handle notify success if it's not declared. **WRONG**. You must register a save handler.

The documentation does not state that `setSettings` is required. **WRONG**. You must set settings or else you will receive this error.

The documentation does not state that you must save a `contentURL`. **WRONG**. You must set content URL in the `setSettings`. You can apparently omit other things when setting your settings, but not content URL.

The documentation does not specifically mention it, but the `contentURL` must comply with your `validURLs` in your manifest. If it does not, you'll also see this error.